# How is it possible that window.innerWidth does NOT return a correct value?

Tags: javascript, width, window-width

Let me describe the very strange issue I encountered.

Browsing with Chrome 97, the javascript command window.innerWidth always sends me back the same value 1920 but on a given website on which it returns 640.

I've first noticed the issue because website layout was obviously designed for mobile clients.

I've been clearing cache, cookies and storages, closed and reopened browser, but issue remains, specific to that website and on no other.

In private session, problem is also present.

But when I test with other browsers (like Chromium or Firefox) : I don't have the problem.

I don't understand how this can be !

Comment: Chrome is Chromium though? What does https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ say?

Comment: Yes Chrome and Chromium are the same, but if you have both installed I guess they count as two separate programs and don't share any data, isn't it ? I've been testing command jQuery(window).width() which also sends me 640 on THIS website only (but 1920 on the others)

Comment: Additional issue here, on the same browser, the console.log function no longer works, this time on any website I visit. WHen I enter command console.log('hello') : hello dos not display I only see undefined... Is it possible that my javascript became somehow disfunctional here on this browser ?

Comment: Or maybe a dysfunctional Chrome update ?

Comment: Please may you open that link with on the dodgy browser?

Comment: I did !  And got values that seemed OK

Comment: Then it’s not likely to be an issue with the browser. Please update the question with a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Well it's hard to reproduce, I could still share a screenshot or video

Comment: Share a [mcve] of the short bit of code used as well